# Multiple sub-fields attached to a field, and how to give the user the possibility of adding many of these fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am building a form in which users (composers) can add a composition. Within this form, alongside title, year, etc, they also add instrumentation.

Each instrument can have a couple of properties, for example 'doubling', and the number of players.

So, for instance:

- title: New composition

  - instrumentation:

    - violin

      - doubled: no
      - players: 1 (this is the 'DoublingAmount', see the models)
    - viola

      - doubled: yes
      - players: 2 (this is the 'DoublingAmount', see the models)
    - cello

      - doubled: no
      - players: 4 (this is the 'DoublingAmount', see the models)

I have created three different models: one for instrumentation, one for the composition, and then one with a ManyToMany relation via a 'through'.

models.py:

```
class Composition(models.Model):

    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
    INSTRUMENT_CHOICES = [('pno', 'piano'), ('vio1', 'violin_1(orchestral section)'), ('vio2', 'violin_2(orchestral section)'),]
    instrumentation = models.ManyToManyField('Instrumentation',
        through='DoublingAmount',
        related_name='compositions',
        max_length=10,
        choices=INSTRUMENT_CHOICES,)

class Instrumentation(models.Model):

    instrumentation = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class DoublingAmount(models.Model):

    DOUBLING_CHOICES =[(1, '1'),(2, '2'), (3, '3')]

    doubling = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    composition = models.ForeignKey(Composition, related_name='doubling_amount', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    instrumentation = models.ForeignKey(Instrumentation, related_name='doubling_amount', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(choices=DOUBLING_CHOICES, default=1)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Composition, Instrumentation

class CompositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title       = forms.CharField(label='Title',
                    widget=forms.TextInput()
    description = forms.CharField()


    class Meta:
        model = Composition
        fields = [
            'title',
            'instrumentation',
        ]
```

views.py:

```
def composition_create_view(request):

    form = CompositionForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = CompositionForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

template.html:

```
    {{ form }}
```

I can see the drop-down list in my form giving the choice of the name of the instrument, and only that. I'd like to have the possibility of selecting name of instrument, doubling yes/no, and quantity. Then I also want to add more instruments, each with its own name, doubling, and quantity. I know this will have to be done via JavaScript, but I don't know how to build the 'behind the scenes' and get Django grab the new items added by the user.

**Update**

I've added a new form in forms.py:

```
class InstrumentationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DoublingAmount
        fields = [
            'doubling',
            'amount',
            'instrumentation'
        ]
```

and linked to the views.py:

```
form_d = InstrumentationForm(request.POST or None)
    [...]
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form_d': form_d
    }
```

and, finally, the template:

```
{{ form_d }}
```

I now have the instrumentation, doubling, and amount fields showing in my template. Am I doing this right? If yes, how can I have Django deal with the user wanting to add or remove instruments? Thanks.

**Update 2**

The issue, which I just realised, is that if I use the DoublingAmount model to store information about the composition's instrument, the object Composition needs to be already created, which of course it's not may case. One solution maybe is to build another form with only 'DoublingAmount' (e.g. instrumentation) information to be displayed after the user has saved the title of the composition. Still, I don't know how to have more than one instrument within the DoublingAmount model without having several objects of DoublingAmount objects for the same composition.

Is there a simpler way to do all this? For example, a 'sub-class' of the composition model?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Composition and then add one Instrument after another like comments to a blog-post. That would probably be the easiest way. Sadly I dont know how to create an array of objects from a form in Django. It's the right way to have more than one object than, thats why its ManyToMany. I would also suggest OneToMay and just two classes:
Composition and instrument with the fields: name, doubled, player-count. But I also dont really get this musician stuff so maybe I am wrong with that :-)

Another way would be using Ajax or stuff like that and create an array in json and transforming that into your instruments. You would need js anyway if you want to dynamically add more instruments (you would need to create input fields and so on).

Comment: Thank you, I've been battling with this all day and I'm still at an impasse. I'm now experimenting with Django formsets, to no avail so far. I might end up just giving up altogether, or using just two classes as I was doing before. Will keep you posted!

Comment: This could be interesting for you:
https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

Comment: Thanks - that's what I tried in the afternoon, when I said that I was experimenting with formsets. I've now found another guide which might help me, fingers crossed. I'll post here any update (hopefully I'll have some soon).

Comment: Thanks, I've actually followed a more recent tutorial and I finally managed to get it working this morning. I'll post my working code later. In the end I reverted to my original idea of having three different models, with the custom 'through'. I'm loving Django more and more.